# How to implement custom font in Xcode playgrounds

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts, swift-playground

I want to change the font of a label with a custom font, but the compiler is giving me an issue:
Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optinal value.
I think that this issue is due to Xcode not recognizing my font file, Brandon_reg.otf. What did I do wrong? Download Playground: https://ufile.io/940cc

```
import UIKit 
import PlaygroundSupport

var view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

let fontURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Brandon_reg", withExtension: "otf")
CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(fontURL! as CFURL, CTFontManagerScope.process, nil)
var font = UIFont(name: "horrendo", size: 30)
var attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : font!,
             NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,
             NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : 0.0] as [String : Any]
let nameAttrSring = NSAttributedString(string: "Brandon_reg", attributes: attrs)

let mainLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = font
    label.textColor = .white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

view.addSubview(mainLabel)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: Is the .otf file in your Resources folder?  What line do you get the error on exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @LouFranco. The .otf file is inside the Resources folder (its name also exactly matches the one in the code). I get the error at this line: `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(fontURL! as CFURL, CTFontManagerScope.process, nil)`.

Comment: I don't think you are getting a problem on that line.  On the right side of the `let fontUrl = ` line, it's showing a `file://` url, not nil, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your font file does not have a font named "horrendo" in it.  This works for me:

```
 var font = UIFont(name: "Brandon Grotesque", size: 30)
```